# Display array's elements grouped by date

Tags: php

I have an array $histories:

```
Array (
Array ([id] => 1, [created] => 2012-12-20 22:40, [message] => 'Message1 to display here'),
Array ([id] => 2, [created] => 2012-12-20 22:40, [message] => 'Message2 to display here'),
Array ([id] => 3, [created] => 2012-12-20 22:40, [message] => 'Message3 to display here'),
Array ([id] => 4, [created] => 2012-12-20 21:30, [message] => 'Message4 to display here'),
Array ([id] => 5, [created] => 2012-12-20 21:30, [message] => 'Message5 to display here'),
Array ([id] => 6, [created] => 2012-12-20 20:20, [message] => 'Message6 to display here'),
);
```

I would like to display messages [message] grouped by date [created] field.

like

```
2012-12-20 22:40
======================
Message1
Message2
Message3

2012-12-20 21:30
======================
Message4
Message5
```

I know there is a function array_count_values() that could help.

Comment: 1. what have you tried; 2. if you got them via MySQL, just `GROUP BY`-them inside your query, otherwise `array_reduce` them to the form you want, or better use a good ol' `foreach`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr_by_dates = array();
foreach($arr as $a){
    if (!isset($arr_by_dates[$a['created']])){
        $arr_by_dates[$a['created']] = array();
    }
    $arr_by_dates[$a['created']][] = $a['message'];
}
```

if you want to save additional information on each record you can use array instead of the message itself:

```
$arr_by_dates = array();
foreach($arr as $a){
    if (!isset($arr_by_dates[$a['created']])){
        $arr_by_dates[$a['created']] = array();
    }
    $arr_by_dates[$a['created']][] = $a;
    // or  = array('message'=>$a['message'], 'id'=>$a['id']);
}
```

Comment: your solution is great but is it possible to build instead: ` $arr_by_dates[$a['created']][] = $a['message'];` to avoid numeric but rather build an associative:`$arr_by_dates[$a['created']]['message'] = $a['message']; $arr_by_dates[$a['created']]['status'] = $a['status']` etc? In my case this mess out; it only get the first element.

Comment: you woudn't want to do that. every element in an array must have an index. default is numeric. what exactly are you trying to achieve? you want both the message and status saved?

Comment: It is important for me to build an associative array instead of numeric so I can display the information based on the key type. If is numeric this is impossible in my case.

Comment: in this case it is associative since 'created' is a timestamp. If you have a numeric key then use $arr_by_dates['_'.$a['created']] instead

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

```
$keys = array();
foreach ($arr as $item) 
{
    $keys[] = strtotime($item['created']);
}
sort($keys);
array_multisort($arr, $keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either convert your structure, and then step through it to print

```
$grouped = array();
foreach( $histories as $row ) {
  $date = $row['created'];
  if ( isset($grouped[$date]) ) {
    $grouped[$date][] = $row;
  }
  else {
    $grouped[$date] = array($row);
  }
}
```

Or you could print it as you go, the latter will depend on your results being ordered by `created` date however:

```
$last = $html = '';
foreach( $histories as $row ) {
  $date = $row['created'];
  if ( $last != $date ) {
    if ( $last ) $html .= '</div>';
    $html .= '<div>';
    $html .= '<h3>'.$date.'</h3>';
    $last = $date;
  }
  $html .= '<p>'.$row['message'].'</p>';
}
$html .= ($html?'</div>':'');
```